# XmlDeserialization of property with Narrowing Operator in type

Tags: vb.net, reflection, xml-serialization

I have created the following custom class to handle specific string ("YYY-MM-DD") as representation of dynamic today value. There is a couple ou Widening, Narrowing and ToString function to help programmers with in-code conversion.

My problem is when I **deserialize**, using XmlSerializer, a class that use MyDateTime. I though that XmlSerializer would use the `Narrowing Operator CType(rightSide As String) As MyDateTime`, as kind of object initializer, before I remerber it uses reflection.

What should I do if I wish that a xml deserialize class property of MyDateTime to be initilized with `Narrowing Operator CType(rightSide As String) As MyDateTime` ??

```
Public Class MyDateTime

Const cstUniversalTodayValue As String = "YYYY-MM-DD"

Dim _internalStringRepresentation As String
Dim _internaValue As MyDateTime

Public ReadOnly Property DynamicToday As Boolean
    Get
        Return _internalStringRepresentation = cstUniversalTodayValue
    End Get
End Property

Public Shared Widening Operator CType(rightSide As MyDateTime) As MyDateTime

    Return rightSide._internaValue
End Operator
Public Shared Widening Operator CType(rightSide As MyDateTime) As String

    Return rightSide._internalStringRepresentation
End Operator

Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(rightSide As MyDateTime) As MyDateTime

    Return New MyDateTime With {._internalStringRepresentation = rightSide.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), ._internaValue = rightSide}
End Operator
Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(rightSide As String) As MyDateTime

    Dim instance = New MyDateTime With {._internalStringRepresentation = rightSide}
    If instance.DynamicToday Then

        instance._internaValue = DateTime.Today
    Else

        instance._internaValue = Convert.ToDateTime(rightSide)
    End If

    Return instance
End Operator

Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return Me
End Function
Public Overloads Function ToString(format As String) As String

    Return _internaValue.ToString(format)
End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XmlSerializer does not use type conversion. Just generate a serializer assembly for your type using the [sgen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bk3w6240%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) tool and browse the generated code via the [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) to understand how it works.

The XmlSerializer instantiates the class executing its constructor and populates its serializable properties later.

To ensure that instaces of your class are properly serialized, implement the [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.aspx) interface. You can also get more control over the XML serialization process by implementing the [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) interface.

Comment: I used the IXmlSerializable to implement custom serialization as I have no Public get/set properties in my object. Many thanks